# ExtJS 4.1.1.a - Keyboard navigation issue at TreePanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm facing keyboard navigation problem with TreePanel. Here's my treepanel configuration:

```
rootVisible: false,
animate: true,
autoScroll: true,
useArrows: true,
border: true,
singleExpand: true,
```

Finally I put the tree as a single item of window; then show it.

I can't use keyboard arrows to expand/collapse items. I can only use up/down arrows to go up & down.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Any helps will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: I can use the left/right arrows to collapse/expand nodes.

Comment: this is the problem I'm facing. Waiting for a solution..

Comment: Ext 4.1.3 [`Ext.tree.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel) Works like expected.. even with the config you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem for my situation was setting selType as rowmodel. After I comment out it, keyboard navigation works as expected..